# How can i display long units in MB and also displaying percentages progress in a progressBar?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have this line:

```
backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress((int)obj.BytesSent);
```

BytesSent is a long var.
I needed to cast it to (int) to report it.

And now in the backgorund1 progresschanged event i want to display it as MB.
For example 0.3MB 0.7MB 33MB instead displaying Bytes.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            toolStripStatusLabel2.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
        }
```

1. How can i display it as MB's instead of Bytes ?
2. How can i calculate and also display in the ProgressChanged event the e.ProgressPercentages as Percentages in a progressBar ? From 0 to 100 depending on the progress in the event:

   private void videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged(IUploadProgress obj)
       {

   ```
           toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = obj.Status.ToString();
           backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress((int)obj.BytesSent);
   }
   ```

I want to show also how much MB's sent and also to show the progress in percentages in a progressBar.

Comment: `How can I display it as MB's instead of Bytes?` Try dividing by the number of bytes in a megabyte, which is 1024. This is just simple unit conversion.

Comment: @Jashaszun That's the wrong number. You mean 1048576, but even that will be argued by some to be wrong, saying it should be 1000000.

Comment: @hvd Haha that's embarassing... yeah that's what I meant. Also, isn't MB generally defined as 1024kB, or (1024*1024) bytes, while MBit is defined as 1000000 bytes?

Comment: @Jashaszun MBit is a number of bits, not bytes, hence the "bit" in it. :) There are separate prefixes for 1048576 and 1000000 bytes, but despite tradition, the official prefixes say 1MB is 1000000 bytes, and 1MiB has been introduced for 1048576 bytes. But there's no universal agreement on it.

Comment: This is just bad code.  You want to tell the user "the job is half done", you cannot do that with BytesSent.  It needs to be 100 * sent / total.  The unit does not matter.  If you don't know *total* then you cannot meaningfully display progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can i display it as MB's instead of Bytes ?

If you bit shift a number every 10 you do will be a unit in size larger so `10` is Kb, `20` is Mb, `30` is Bytes, and so on. So if you divide your number by `1 << 20` you will be dividing by the number of bytes in a megabyte giving you the total in megabytes.

```
double mbSent = ((double)obj.BytesSent) / (1 << 20);
```

I cast BytesSent to a `double` first so we don't get integer division.

> How can i calculate and also display in the ProgressChanged event the e.ProgressPercentages as Percentages in a progressBar.

For that just divide BytesSent by the total number of bytes there is then multiply by 100.

```
double percentComplete = ((double)obj.BytesSent) / totalBytes * 100;
```

You can then assign percentComplete to your progress bar's value.

Comment: Scott is that right ? double mbSent = ((double)obj.BytesSent) / (1 << 20);
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress((int)mbSent); i have to cast it to (int) since ReportProgress get only int.

Comment: totalBytes is the file size in bytes ?

Comment: For the first part yes, however you said you wanted to do `0.3MB` which you can't do if you are casting to `int`, for the second part if you are sending a file then yes it is the file size in bytes.

Answer (score 0):

To display size in MB you should take size in B and divide it by 1024^2. To show progress in percentages you have to take size of part which was downloaded and divide it by size of file.